# How to detect double-tap in custom component in HarmonyOS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am creating a custom component in HarmonyOS using Java SDK, Where I have to perform some task on double-tap. But I am not able to detect double-tap event.

In Android, with the help of **GestureDetector** class we can detect double-tap event as follow:

```
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                return super.onDoubleTap(e);
            }
        });
```

In HMOS, I have tried to detect double-tap using **Component.TouchEventListener** as follow:

```
Component.TouchEventListener touchEventListener = new TouchEventListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(Component component, TouchEvent touchEvent) {
                if(touchEvent.getPointerCount() == 1) {
                    LogUtil.info(TAG, "single click detected");
                }

                if(touchEvent.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                    LogUtil.info(TAG, "double click detected");
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
```

but, It has not detected double-tap. On double-tap also it has printed **single click detected**.

Comment: the answer posted by Gowtham must work because that's the direct callback. Between just FYI - getPointerCount() returns the number of touche pointers for the same event. For example -You can use it to find how many fingers are used for the same touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try registering [**Component.DoubleClickedListener**](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/component_doubleclickedlistener-0000001071641454)  and you will be able to detect Double Tap in Custom Component, sample Usage

```java
    customComponent.setDoubleClickedListener(new Component.DoubleClickedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDoubleClick(Component component) {
                    LogUtil.info(TAG, "double click detected");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Is there any other callback or api where I also get instance of **TouchEvent**.

Comment: How to do that in smart devices, so JS not Java?

Answer (score 1):

Supports component double-clicking in SDK API Version 5 or later.

As@[Gowtham GS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10472898/gowtham-gs) mentioned, sample usage is as follows:

```
customComponent.setDoubleClickedListener(new Component.DoubleClickedListener() {                
                @Override
                public void onDoubleClick(Component component) {
                    LogUtil.info(TAG, "double click detected");
                }
            });
```